# How to get the serveur address where google interior view images are stocked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google maps API v3 to create a portfolio.

Question :

> Is there a way to generate the default image link, that would work on every google server, or a way to know what server is used so I can generate the link accordingly ?

---

**Here is an example of what I'm currently doing. It may or may not help you finding an answer**

User path :

- The user enters the address of his business.
- An iframe is displayed with the interior view of this business
- The user can navigate on this iframe to select his default picture

From the view selected with the iframe, I can create an image URL directly from the Google servers that I set as default image.

At the moment, this URL can be (JS):

```
var image = "https://geo3.ggpht.com/cbk?panoid=" + panoId + "&output=thumbnail&cb_client=search.LOCAL_UNIVERSAL.gps&thumb=2&w=689&h=487&yaw=" + povHeading + "&pitch=" + povPitch + "&thumbfov=" + fov;
```

or

```
var image = "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/" + panoId + "/w689-h487-k-no-pi"+povPitch+"-ya"+povHeading+"-ro0-fo"+fov+"/";
```

This worked for a vast majority of the cases, but as more people are using the service, some special cases appeared (example link) :

https://lh3.ggpht.com/-1dwRgcXpyYk/WS7bUYtLEdI/AAAAAAAAObA/zd-aK-rfWxYvA302eg6WT7qQoEKRrUxGgCLIB/x2-y2-z3/p

I am saving the link for the both first cases but I have not found a general rule that can be applied. 
The user that entered his business having this 3rd example link is getting a 404 img not found atm.

Here is the code I'm currently using, if it can help understanding the question (JS):

```js
function generateImg() {

    /* here I get all the vars used to create the image */

    //generate img link
    var image = "https://geo3.ggpht.com/cbk?panoid=" + panoId + "&output=thumbnail&cb_client=search.LOCAL_UNIVERSAL.gps&thumb=2&w=689&h=487&yaw=" + povHeading + "&pitch=" + povPitch + "&thumbfov=" + fov;

    //if img does not exist
    UrlExists(image, function(status){
        if(status === 404){
            // 404 not found
            var image = "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/" + panoId + "/w689-h487-k-no-pi"+povPitch+"-ya"+povHeading+"-ro0-fo"+fov+"/";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In the third example, do you still get the `panoId` ? Could you not use the Street View API to get the image you require? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro if you have the panoID, heading and FOV, then that should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the consistent result within the official API:

```
var image = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&pano=" + panoId + "&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=" + API_KEY;
```